# How to adjust reference date to convert a date to numeric to get the intercept shown in plot

Tags: r, date, numeric

I want to know if I can change the calculation of the number of seconds that have passed between 01/01/2012 and 01/01/2011 and not from 01/01/1970. Is there a possibility to change it?

The problem is that the interecept I get from the model does not match the one in the plot

I am using the as.numeric to convert date to numeric to get the prediction from this model.

Here is the data:

```
year <- c("2011-01-01", "2012-01-01", "2013-01-01", "2014-01-01", "2015-01-01", "2016-01-01", "2017-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2019-01-01", "2020-01-01", "2021-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2014-01-01", "2018-01-01", "2011-01-01", "2022-01-01")
year <- as.Date(year, "%Y-%m-%d"
type <- rep(c(1,2),each=8))
```

Here is the model:

```
mod1<-lm(data$region1~data$Year)
```

[image]

Comment: Or `difftime(as.POSIXct("2012-01-01"), as.POSIXct("2011-01-01"), units = "secs")`

Comment: Can I use this differences to get a linear model?

Comment: Unclear what you are asking. Do you want an ARIMA model that uses differencing to demean the sequence?? I'm wondering if you should be going to CrossValidated.com to get your methods lined up before trying to code it in R. Ypu clearly have not learned how to post on SO, since you have used images instead of text.